# Pirâmide etária com ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Fiz um pirâmide etária utilizando o código abaixo:

```
ggplot(data = piramide, 
       mapping = aes(x = `Faixa etária`,
                     y = ifelse(test = sexo == "Feminino",  yes = pop, no = -pop), fill = sexo)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = abs, limits = (max(piramide$pop))* c(-1,1)) +
  labs(y = "População", x = "Faixa etária (em anos)") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1", direction = -1) +
  coord_flip()
```

O resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de colocar a população da mesma forma que está no banco, exemplo: 401.425 e alterar a ordem da categoria sexo no gráfico

o dataframe:

```
structure(list(`Faixa etária` = c("60 a 69", "70 a 79", "80 a 89", 
"90 ou mais", "60 a 69", "70 a 79", "80 a 89", "90 ou mais"), 
    sexo = c("Feminino", "Feminino", "Feminino", "Feminino", 
    "Masculino", "Masculino", "Masculino", "Masculino"), pop = c(401425, 
    242451, 118671, 36191, 288951, 150313, 57404, 11262)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Mais específico que este tópico !?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por padrão, o R coloca os níveis de uma variável categórica em ordem alfabética. Supondo que `sexo` é o vetor ou coluna de data frame com uma variável categórica, uma maneira de colocar esses níveis na ordem desejada pelo usuário é através do comando `factor(sexo, levels = ("Masculino", "Feminino"))`.

Para retirar números do formato científico (ou seja, em vez de 4e+05, ter 400.000), é preciso usar os argumentos `big.mark = "."` e `scientific = FALSE` dentro do argumento `labels` de `scale_y_continuous`. O problema é que, por padrão, eles não podem ser definidos simultaneamente.

Para resolver isso, criei uma função chamada `abs_virgula`, que coloca os teus números em valor absoluto, no formato não científico, com separador de milhar (`big.mark`) sendo igual a ponto. Coloquei também `decimal.mark = ","`, que não é necessário no teu caso específico, pois teus números são inteiros.

Entretanto, ao definir `big.mark = "."`, é preciso definir um novo separador decimal para não rolar confusão na notação e evitar um aviso de warning. Não é algo obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática.

Juntando tudo isso, temos o resultado abaixo:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

abs_virgula <- function (x) {
  format(abs(x), big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE)
}

piramide %>%
  mutate(sexo = factor(sexo, levels = c("Masculino", "Feminino"))) %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = `Faixa etária`,
                       y = ifelse(sexo == "Feminino",  yes = pop, no = -pop), fill = sexo)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = abs_virgula, limits = (max(piramide$pop))* c(-1,1)) +
  labs(y = "População", x = "Faixa etária (em anos)") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1", direction = 1) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>